# Spring boot test - EntityManager does not persist when using 2 databases

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have Spring Boot test for controller:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ExampleDAO;

    @Test
    public void someTest(){

        exampleDAO.save(someEntity);

        // call to endpoint
    }
}
```

I have two database configs:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryManagerFactory", basePackages = { "com.example.repository.primary" })
public class PrimaryDbConfig {
```

And

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "anotherManagerFactory", basePackages = { "com.example.repository.another" })
public class AnotherDbConfig {
```

Test properties fragment:

```
spring.primary.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:primary;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.primary.datasource.username=sa
spring.primary.datasource.password=
spring.primary.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.another.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:another;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.another.datasource.username=sa
spring.another.datasource.password=
spring.another.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
```

GenericDAOImpl fragment:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "another-persistence-unit")
protected EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
@Transactional
public void save(T entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
}
```

When I run test, `exampleDAO.save(someEntity)` method does not save or output any SQL to logs. `exampleDAO` is not primary data source.

If I change to:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void save(T entity) {
    entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).save(entity);
}
```

It works well and persists data. However, the same method with primary data source DAO persists entities with `EntityManager`.

Why does it save entity with `Session` but not with `EntityManager`?

Comment: I guess you should create two transaction managers and specify the name of it at Transnational annotation.

Comment: Two transaction managers are created in DB configs. If I make @Transactional(transactionManager = "anotherTransactionManager") then EntityManager persists data. Strange why it was difference between Session and EntityManager.

Comment: I guess Session.save() has internal transaction whilst EntityManager.persist bases only on TransactionManager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case of using two DBs separate TransactionManager-s should be created and **specified**

```
@Override
@Transactional("transactionManagerName")
public void save(T entity) {
   entityManager.persist(entity);
}
```